# Dynamically include .js files from Zend_Controller_Action?

Tags: zend-framework

I came across the case where depending on the execution path I may need to invoke an inclusion of .js file from controller. Is there a nice way of doing it? (besides setting some view variable with actual .js include code)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the view helper headScript(). I'm just writing this off the top of my head but I think it works like this:

From within a view file: `$this->headScript()->appendFile('filename.js');`

From within a controller: `$this->view->headScript()->appendFile('filename.js');`

And then somewhere in your layout you need to echo out your headScript object:

`<?=$this->headScript();?>`

Comment: While this is the correct answer, how do you handle situations where you have a set of JS files that are pre-reqs for the entire site, plus these one-offs that need to be included on certain controller pages? I find appending here causes them to appear BEFORE the "core" set is loaded...?

Comment: I think you're looking for prependFile(). You can either statically include the necessary files in your layout or call to prependFile() somewhere along the way.

Comment: yep, that's it... prepend in the header, append in the views. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you could do like @Bill Karwin described.

But if you would like to do it really nicely, you need template inheritance - like it is implemented in Django framework for Python for instance. There are some extensions for Zend Framework as well, take a look at [Calypso](http://www.beberlei.de/calypso/).